# Optional default value for get_in Access behavior elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there an option to add a default fallback value in [`get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2)?

Scenario:

```
merge_maps = get_in(
  payload, ["msg", "clicks"]
) ++ get_in(
  payload, ["msg", "opens"]
)
```

if the key `"clicks"` or `"opens"` isn't found in the nested `"msg"` map, `get_in/2` will return `nil` which then thrown an error:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.++(nil, nil)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:250: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/5
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:230: IEx.Evaluator.do_eval/3
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:208: IEx.Evaluator.eval/3
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:94: IEx.Evaluator.loop/1
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:24: IEx.Evaluator.init/4
```

Would be nice to be able to do something like

```
get_in(payload, ["msg", "clicks"], [])
```

where the empty list would be the fallback value if no value with that key is found. What's the right way to achieve this?

**Update**

Thanks to the answer from @PatNowak I implemented a wrapper around `get_in`:

```
defmodule Helpers.AccessHelper do
  def get_in_attempt(data, keys, default \\ []) do
    case get_in(data, keys) do
      nil -> default
      result -> result
    end
  end
end
```

And then in another file:

```
import Helpers.AccessHelper, only: [get_in_attempt: 2]

merge_maps = get_in_attempt(
  payload, ["msg", "clicks"]
) ++ get_in_attempt(
  payload, ["msg", "opens"]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own wrapper for `Kernel.get_in/2`, but with using default value as a fallback.

```
def get_in_attempt(data, keys, default) do
  case get_in(data, keys) do
    nil-> default
    result -> result
  end
end
```

so in your case it's enough to have

```
def get_in_attempt(data, keys) do
  case get_in(data, keys) do
    nil-> [] # your default is set, so don't need to pass it
    result -> result
  end
end
```

However, using first approach (with explicit `default` argument is more flexible and can be reused in different scenarios).

Comment: that's an elegant way to solve this problem thank you. Where would that live within a Phoenix 1.3 app? Looking for the best place to add that. Also is this considered a Protocol?

Comment: No, it's not protocol, as protocols work for particular data structures and we will not somehow overwrite Access protocol :) For something like this I have `helpers` directory which lies in `lib`, not in `lib/web`.

Comment: good to know. And where would this function live inside a Phoenix app? Any suggestions?

Comment: Check my edited comment. I use `helpers` directory as it's universal function that can be applied everywhere and doesn't handle business logic.

Comment: perfect that explains it well :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way, You can use the `||` operator ([doc](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html)).

```
merge_maps = (get_in(
  payload, ["msg", "clicks"]
) || [] ) ++ ( get_in(
  payload, ["msg", "opens"]
) || [] )
```

So if `get_in` return nil, the `[]` will be chosen like a default value

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [`Access.key/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#key/2) in this case. The keys in `Kernel.get_in` can be functions, so you can swap out your list of string keys with  Access functions (`Access.key/2` supports a default value if the key is not found).

Something like this:

`get_in(payload, ["msg", Access.key("clicks", []))`